# Macro copy a row then paste it to another third party application

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is it possible to create a macro recording that copies a row value then paste it to another webpage or third-party application? Then after I paste it, it will move to the next row and paste it again to that webpage or third-party application? So it will be on a loop until it reaches a blank row

Comment: Are you asking for Apps Script to modify other applications/pages? Could you explain your case specifically?

Comment: @Marti I need to fill up a form from a website that contains rows of input fields. The values that I need to put in these input fields are inside a spreadsheet. There is no import function in the website so I wonder if the faster way could be doing a macro that copies the value per row and paste it to the target input fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible inside Google Sheets. You should use some automation tool for this.

Free tool: wildfire.ai - that works as a plugin to Chrome Browser. This way you can simulate keyboard actions.

Professional tool: Microsoft Power Automate - standalone application.